# Adding an id or class to content of a page-template dynamically in WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, events

I'm having an issue regarding styling some pages that are being created dynamicly to some tags on WordPress site.

I have a WordPress installation and I'm displaying events with the Events Manager plugin (by. Marcus Sykes). I'm with it using tags to better categorise all the events like *All events*, *Outdoor events* a.s.o. And users can then click on these tag links on the given event. The events manager uses a *Tags* page to handle all tags then created. So when a user clicks on ex. the *All events* tag link, on an event, it would then open this URL: www.testsite.com/tags/all-events.

I would then like to add a `class` or `id` to the content section for all the events because I want to use `flex` on all the posts that show up under the tags page. A little bit confusing sorry...

So I tried to create a custom page template that the *Tags* page uses but I don't know how to wrap a `class` or an `id` around all the content that gets added to it dynamically (all the events that use that specific tag), am I thinking about this the wrong way? Or should I do it some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You check whether the particular **event tags are available in the URL**, then **select all the html tags you want to add a class to** (those that are wrappers for your events I assume), and then **add the class**.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (window.location.pathname.indexOf("tags/all-events") > -1) {
        $('yourSelectorForAllTheEventTags').addClass("yourEventClassName");
}
```

Hope that helps!